# reading data from s3 by jupyter notebook in ubuntu ec2 deep learning instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I have several txt and csv datasets in one s3 bucket, my_bucket, and a deep learning ubuntu ec2 instance. I am using Jupyter notebook on this instance. I need to read data from s3 to Jupyter.

I searched everywhere (almost) in AWS documentation and their forum together with other blogs. This is the best I could do. However, after getting the keys (both) restarting the instance (and aws too) I still get an error for aws_key.

I'm wondering if anyone ran to this or you have a better idea to get the data from there. I'm open as long as it's not using http (which requires the data to be public). Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
from smart_open import smart_open
import os

aws_key = os.environ['aws_key']
aws_secret = os.environ['aws_secret']

bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
object_key = 'data.csv'

path = 's3://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(aws_key, aws_secret, bucket_name, object_key)

df = pd.read_csv(smart_open(path))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample would work if you export the `aws_key` and first `aws_secret`. Something like this would work (assuming bash is your shell):

```
export aws_key=<your key>
export aws_secret=<your aws secret>
python yourscript.py
```

It is best practice to export things like keys and secrets so that you are not storing confidential/secret things in your source code. If you were to hard code those values into your script and accidentally commit them to a public repo, it would be easy for someone to take over your aws account.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question here and would like to hear from community too on different solutions: Directly access S3 data from the Ubuntu Deep Learning instance by

```
cd ~/.aws
aws configure
```

Then update aws key and secret key for the instance, just to make sure. Checke awscli version using the command:

```
aws --version
```

Read more on configuration

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
```

In the above code, "aws_key" and "aws_secret" are not listed as environmental variables on the Ubuntu instance and hence the inbuilt function os.environ cannot be used

```
aws_key = 'aws_key'
aws_secret = 'aws_secret'
```